# Replacing compiz/metacity with openbox reduces workspaces to 1

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, window-manager, openbox

I like to use the GNOME desktop, but I prefer to replace its window manager with openbox, with 4 workspaces.  However, when I run `openbox --replace`, the number of workspaces available drops to 1.  If I go into obconf, workspaces is still configured to be 4 (`~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` shows the same).  I can get the workspaces to reappear by changing the value in obconf to anything else, and then back to 4.

I have just been dealing with this problem since Ubuntu 9.04 (now up to 10.10) since I don't reboot very often.  But it's really annoying to have to reset my workspaces whenever I do have to reboot.  Changing the value in rc.xml and running `openbox --reconfigure` does not seem to have any effect.  So what is obconf doing that I'm not (sends a dbus message perhaps [EDIT: watching with `dbus-monitor` I see no messages when changing the workspaces value in obconf])?

I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to change the window manager than just running `openbox --replace` at login.  So my questions are:

1. Is there a better way to specify an alternate window manager (i.e. a way that doesn't cause the workspaces to break)?
2. If not, how can I automatically set the number of workspaces back to 4?

**Update:**

I finally got around to trying what I commented on MrShunz's answer (adding `WINDOW_MANAGER=/usr/bin/openbox` to `~/.gnomerc`).  But the effect is the same as `openbox --replace`.

**Another Update** (in response to geekosaur):

When running `xprop -root -spy` I see this (among other values):

```
_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS(CARDINAL) = 1
_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES(UTF8_STRING) = 0x57, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6b, 0x73, 0x70, 0x61, 0x63, 0x65, 0x20, 0x31, 0x0
```

But I suppose that makes sense, because when I start openbox from a terminal, it says this:

```
Openbox-WARNING **: Openbox is configured for 4 desktops, but the current session has 1.  Overriding the Openbox configuration.
```

But that is a lie, because metacity, which is the active window manager when openbox takes over, is configured for four desktops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally stumbled upon a work-around for this.  Instead of running `openbox --replace` at startup, I run a script with the following:

```
openbox --replace &
metacity --replace &
openbox --replace &
```

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround: starting odconf and adjusting the number of workspaces brings the workspaces back as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try configuring as you like it to work and then saving the session as it's suggested [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=75471).

Comment: That is how I set it up (`openbox --replace` and then saved the session).  But whenever I log in, I only have one workspace.  I'll have to try post #5 on that page, though, which is adding `export WINDOW_MANAGER=/usr/bin/openbox` to `~/.gnomerc`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested in seeing output from `xprop -root -spy | grep --line-buffered _NET_` when you start OpenBox; my guess is it's not placing the right `_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS` and/or `_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES` atoms on the root window at startup, and changing the setting causes it to put the right values there.  If so, you'll want to file that as a bug against OpenBox.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: @Brian, I think you just confirmed my suspicion.  I would, however, guess that Metacity removes its desktop definitions when it exits, so OpenBox tries to initialize, finds nothing, and defaults to a single desktop.  This is more of an OpenBox question, though; you should file a bug report with them.